# Multiple Typeorm Transactions never completing/erroring nor running

Tags: mysql, transactions, typeorm, mysql2

I am running a setup with NestJs and Typeorm and a MySql 5.7 DB. As a driver we use mysql2.

Something is causing events where one part of the logic is triggered multiple times within milliseconds. In this logic we are opening the following transaction:

```
await typeorm.getManager().transaction('READ UNCOMMITTED', async (entityManager) => {...});
```

This is reflected in the logs by the following:

```
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
query: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
.
.
.
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
```

After the transactions are started, no futher code is executed. There are no logs, no errors, nothing. The transactions do not commit, abort or rollback.

Doing research about possible limitations from MySQL did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage do solve this issue?

Comment: sadly not, we just started to introduce some timouts.... worst hack ever.

Comment: TypeORM does some funky stuff with transactions. Try writing custom queries in MySQL.